# Valgrind C/C++ Unitialized value created by stack allocation used outside the stack

Tags: c, valgrind

I got a strange findings in valgrind memcheck, I cannot share the whole code (huge and proprietary), but here is a simplified version:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
     func2(modu2.c:12631)
     func1(modu1.c:1808)
     main(main.c:1808)
  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
     func1_1(modu1.c:691)
```

func1_1 is called inside func1, all variables created by stack allocation should have been deleted at the end of the function, func2 is never (triple checked) called inside func1_1.

Question 1: Does it has some reasonable explanation other than Valgrind has gone mad? Could some build flags/configuration trigger such issues?

Also, inside func2, the code look like that:

```
void func2(var input)
{
   var tmp = 0;
   tmp = input.x + input.y;
   if(tmp < 100) // here was the use
      doStuff();
}
```

Question 2: tmp is clearly initialized, could Valgrind send a finding if input.x was not? Both of them? Valgrind crazy?

Thank you very much, this issue is driving me crazy and I am pushing for tool to be part of the process, but I have to proof that it is reliable.

Comment: Is your `var input` in any way created by `func1_1`? The first thing that comes to my mind is that you have a pointer to a local variable from `func1_1`, which has escaped to `func1` and from there to `func2`.

Comment: valgrind is a standard and widely used tool (see e.g. https://valgrind.org/gallery/users.html), I would question any code very long before I suspect valgrind, just saying..

Comment: I recommend you start removing code until you have the smallest possible program that still produces the warning. That should give you some idea where the problem is, and give you some code to post here for us to look at.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it's not productive to try and answer the question. "Something like this" code is not useful as it's likely not showing the problem in the real code unless it is an MVE.

Comment: @rtoijala not directly, I'm actually thinking about some kind of shared static variable, or maybe a wrong memcpy but not sure if Valgrind could catch that. Also, removing the code is really feasible here, the codebase is a million lines of code and the two parts are in different subsystems. But I tried to memset (0 and 255) the unitialized and monitor the value of the other, and indeed there is a difference (75 vs 77).

Comment: @Yuri Feldman True, I am pretty sure the issue is in the code.

Comment: "*I have to proof that it is reliable.*" Valgrind is an industry standard tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example, where `tmp` is initialized in some sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct { int x; int y; } Point;

void foo(const Point *p)
{
    int tmp = p->x;
    Point *q = new Point;
    if (tmp < 742) { delete q; delete q; }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point p;
    // p.x = 1000;
    foo(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind issues a valid error, since `tmp` depends on
the value of `p.x` which was *not* initialized:

```
$ g++ -g -O0 main.cpp -o main
$ valgrind ./main
==27183== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27183== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27183== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27183== Command: ./main
==27183== 
==27183== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27183==    at 0x108774: foo(Point const*) (main7.cpp:10)
==27183==    by 0x1087C4: main (main7.cpp:17)
==27183== 
==27183== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
...
==27183== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When I remove the comment and initialize `p.x` everything goes fine.
So the short answer for you is that **yes, valgrind uses analyzes that
enable him to monitor uninitialized variables, and propagate these values on**.
When an `if (exp) { ... }` is encountered with exp having an uninitialized value,
both branches are considered

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that copying will propagate, but does Valgrind also propagate on more complex equation? Like tmp = p->x * 100 / sqrt(initializedVariable);

Comment: @IkarRahl: yes, valgrind tracks undefinedness including in complex expressions.  See https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.machine for a detailed description.

Comment: Thanks, that make things clearer ... and more complicated, I guess it also tracks then memcpy of an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @IkarRahl yes, it fully tracks undefinedness for every instruction executed. Copying memory is not different: it is just a bunch of instructions that are executed, like any other function.